# Why the request doesn't send to server in some situations?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have created a website with Asp.net and c# language.
The website is uploaded to a special server in an organization.
When I open the website from my workplace or any other places through the internet the site works properly and I don't have any problem. 
But when I open it in that organization which the website is uploaded there through the internet I have some problems.
Most of the times when I click on the links or buttons the request doesn't send to server and I should click again and again on the links.
I have used some update panels for state and city dropdown listboxes to prevent post back, but when I change the first dropdown the second dropdown doesn't fill and user must refresh the page.
Please help me.

Comment: perhaps their DNS or proxy or... is doing something special - we had such a case with some rather security-savvy customer... solution was to configure the browser (client-side) so that it did not use the proxy when accessing that server...

Comment: Please give me more information. you said about DNS is doing something special. Could you give me more info. Is firewall effective? They use Kerio firewall.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several things affecting you application. First you need to make sure you have tested your site on different browsers. Different browsers and versions can have different behaviours and bugs.

Secondly, have you checked that there isn't any proxy settings required to be able to access the site?

Comment: There is no problem on different browsers. There is no proxy in the browser too? What to do? Please help me

Comment: Is firewall effective? They use kerio firewall.

Comment: Have you checked with network admin for firewall ruels or proxy settings? If there is a different behaviour depending on your location on the network, there has to be something in between your browser and your web app. Also make sure you put enough logs in your app so you can investigate if it is not an application error as opposed to network issue. Think of all the different parameters, different account, network location, timezone... you need to do more investigation!